# Using multiple regex in XSLT : how to reduce processing time

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, saxon

I am quite new to programming and XSLT: I try to improve the way I ask questions and explain problems, but I still have a long way to go. Sorry if there is something unclear.

I need to detect various alphabets in my XML document, which looks like this, with a lot more different language options.

```
<text>
<p>Some text. dise´mbər Some text. Some text.</p> <!-- text in International Phonetic Alphabet + English -->
<p>Some text. dise´mbər Some text. Издательство Академии Наук СССР Some text.</p> <!-- text in International Phonetic Alphabet +  English + Cyrillic alphabet -->
<p>Some text. Издательство Академии Наук СССР dise´mbər Some text.  Some text.</p>
<p>Some text. Some text. Издательство Академии Наук СССР Some text.</p> <!-- text in English + Cyrillic alphabet -->
</text>
```

What I started to do in XSLT is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
   
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:processing-instruction>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="IPA">
      <xsl:variable name="text" ><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="((\p{{IsIPAExtensions}}|\p{{IsPhoneticExtensions}})+)" >
         
         <xsl:matching-substring>
            <IPA><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></IPA>
         </xsl:matching-substring>
         <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of></xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:template>
   
   
   <xsl:template name="Cyrillic">
      <xsl:variable name="texte" ><xsl:call-template name="IPA"></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$texte" regex="(\p{{IsCyrillic}}+)" >
         
         <xsl:matching-substring>
            <Cyrillic><xsl:apply-templates select="regex-group(1)"/></Cyrillic>
         </xsl:matching-substring>
         <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:call-template name="IPA"></xsl:call-template></xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:template>
   
   
   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:call-template name="Cyrillic"></xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So that I could get an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><text>
<p>Some text. dise´mb<IPA>ə</IPA>r Some text. Some text.</p>  
<p>Some text. dise´mb<IPA>ə</IPA>r Some text. <Cyrillic>Издательство</Cyrillic>   <Cyrillic>Академии</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>Наук</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>СССР</Cyrillic> Some text.</p>  
<p>Some text. <Cyrillic>Издательство</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>Академии</Cyrillic>
<Cyrillic>Наук</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>СССР</Cyrillic> dise´mb<IPA>ə</IPA>r Some text.  Some text.</p>
<p>Some text. Some text. <Cyrillic>Издательство</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>Академии</Cyrillic>   
<Cyrillic>Наук</Cyrillic> <Cyrillic>СССР</Cyrillic> Some text.</p>   
</text>
```

This is what I needed, however, there is a ten or so  regex blocks that I use and the processing time will be quite long if I use this method. What would you do instead? Do you think XSLT is appropriate for this?

Thank you !
Maria
(XSLT 2, Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8)

Edit: here's the profile:

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Analysis of Stylesheet Execution Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Analysis of Stylesheet Execution Time</h1>
     <p>Total time: 72128.065 milliseconds</p>
     <h2>Time spent in each template, function or global variable:</h2>
     <p>The table below is ordered by the total net time spent in the template,     function
     or global variable. Gross time means the time including called templates and functions
     (recursive calls only count from the original entry);  net time means time excluding
     time spent in called templates and functions.
     </p>
     <table border="border" cellpadding="10">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>file</th>
     <th>line</th>
     <th>instruction</th>
     <th>count</th>
     <th>average time (gross/ms)</th>
     <th>total time (gross/ms)</th>
     <th>average time (net/ms)</th>
     <th>total time (net/ms)</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>21</td>
     <td>template Greek</td>
     <td align="right">2,755,968</td>
     <td align="right">0.017</td>
     <td align="right">46,854.785</td>
     <td align="right">0.017</td>
     <td align="right">46,854.785</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>32</td>
     <td>template Hebrew</td>
     <td align="right">1,329,696</td>
     <td align="right">0.043</td>
     <td align="right">57,529.163</td>
     <td align="right">0.008</td>
     <td align="right">10,674.378</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>54</td>
     <td>template IPA</td>
     <td align="right">333,984</td>
     <td align="right">0.206</td>
     <td align="right">68,964.076</td>
     <td align="right">0.019</td>
     <td align="right">6,381.186</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>43</td>
     <td>template Cyrillic</td>
     <td align="right">665,392</td>
     <td align="right">0.094</td>
     <td align="right">62,582.890</td>
     <td align="right">0.008</td>
     <td align="right">5,053.727</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>65</td>
     <td>template Arabic</td>
     <td align="right">167,068</td>
     <td align="right">0.421</td>
     <td align="right">70,284.800</td>
     <td align="right">0.008</td>
     <td align="right">1,320.724</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>76</td>
     <td>template Arrows</td>
     <td align="right">83,536</td>
     <td align="right">0.849</td>
     <td align="right">70,945.946</td>
     <td align="right">0.008</td>
     <td align="right">661.146</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>template *</td>
     <td align="right">12,122</td>
     <td align="right">5.959</td>
     <td align="right">72,238.100</td>
     <td align="right">0.034</td>
     <td align="right">413.937</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>87</td>
     <td>template Dingbats</td>
     <td align="right">41,768</td>
     <td align="right">1.708</td>
     <td align="right">71,323.074</td>
     <td align="right">0.009</td>
     <td align="right">377.128</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>98</td>
     <td>template Private</td>
     <td align="right">20,884</td>
     <td align="right">3.427</td>
     <td align="right">71,576.916</td>
     <td align="right">0.012</td>
     <td align="right">253.842</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>18</td>
     <td>template processing-instruction()</td>
     <td align="right">6,907</td>
     <td align="right">0.014</td>
     <td align="right">98.490</td>
     <td align="right">0.014</td>
     <td align="right">98.490</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>     "*code/unicode.xsl"      </td>
     <td>121</td>
     <td>template text()</td>
     <td align="right">20,884</td>
     <td align="right">3.429</td>
     <td align="right">71,600.976</td>
     <td align="right">0.001</td>
     <td align="right">24.060</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The profile of Martin Honnen's code:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Analysis of Stylesheet Execution Time</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Analysis of Stylesheet Execution Time</h1>
      <p>Total time: 2900.594 milliseconds</p>
      <h2>Time spent in each template, function or global variable:</h2>
      <p>The table below is ordered by the total net time spent in the template,    function
         or global variable. Gross time means the time including called templates and functions
         (recursive calls only count from the original entry);  net time means time excluding
         time spent in called templates and functions.
      </p>
      <table border="border" cellpadding="10">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>file</th>
               <th>line</th>
               <th>instruction</th>
               <th>count</th>
               <th>average time (gross/ms)</th>
               <th>total time (gross/ms)</th>
               <th>average time (net/ms)</th>
               <th>total time (net/ms)</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>            "*code/unicode.xsl"       </td>
               <td>44</td>
               <td>template text()</td>
               <td align="right">222,968</td>
               <td align="right">0.009</td>
               <td align="right">1,949.720</td>
               <td align="right">0.009</td>
               <td align="right">1,949.720</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>            "*code/unicode.xsl"       </td>
               <td>26</td>
               <td>template text()</td>
               <td align="right">20,884</td>
               <td align="right">0.135</td>
               <td align="right">2,823.597</td>
               <td align="right">0.042</td>
               <td align="right">873.877</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will be quite long? Have you run any tests and can share some numbers?

Comment: For an input XML of 3346 lines, the Tree is built in 181.7456ms
Tree size: 40488 nodes, 668645 characters, 5271 attributes
Execution time: 51.580351s (51580.3516ms)
Memory used: 15 988 264. It is ok for what I need, but I would like to know whether there is a faster/more elegant way to do this as I am learning on my own.

Comment: Tree built in 327.6848ms
Tree size: 240934 nodes, 11022801 characters, 26129 attributes
Execution time: 10m 22.454917s (622454.9176ms)
Memory used: 56 700 640

Comment: Is the stuff in the posted code that is unrelated to analyze-string/regular expression use needed that way it is written? Do you need to strip namespaces from element names and attribute names and processing instruction names?

Comment: As for the performance, Saxon has an option http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html to profile your code to see where the time is spent, so I would suggest to look at that first. Also, do you need to run the same stylesheet against several files? It helps compiling the XSLT once and then to run it against the several input files, how you do that depends on how you run Saxon, I think from the command line you can give it a directory of input files, from the API cache the compiled stylesheet.

Comment: no, it is not needed the way it is written.

Comment: To simplify the whole approach and make the code more compact, easier to read and understand, I would suggest, given that Saxon 9.8 is an XSLT 3 processor, to simply use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as a top-level declaration. That way you don't need to write any templates to copy elements, attributes and processing instructions through. It should also hopefully slightly improve the performance compared to all the `local-name()` transformations. Then the performance profile needs to tell us where to look further.

Comment: thank you! I will do that. And yes, this stylesheet will be used against several files.  I added the profile of the XML file I tested first to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3, I would consider the following approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="scripts"
    as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*"
    select="map { 'Cyrillic' : '\p{IsCyrillic}+'},
            map { 'IPA' : '[\p{IsIPAExtensions}\p{IsPhoneticExtensions}]+' }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:iterate select="$scripts">
          <xsl:param name="input" select="."/>
          <xsl:on-completion>
              <xsl:sequence select="$input"/>
          </xsl:on-completion>
          <xsl:next-iteration>
              <xsl:with-param name="input">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$input" mode="wrap">
                      <xsl:with-param name="script-map" tunnel="yes" select="."/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:iterate>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="wrap" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="wrap">
      <xsl:param name="script-map" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$script-map?*}">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:element name="{map:keys($script-map)}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>              
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't measured whether it performs better but for the regular expressions I would `[\p{IsIPAExtensions}\p{IsPhoneticExtensions}]+` consider to be easier than `(\p{IsIPAExtensions}|\p{IsPhoneticExtensions})+`.

The other improvements are to rely on the `xsl:mode` based identity transformation and `xsl:iterate`.

Comment: @Maria: You accepted this answer, but I would be interested to know whether there was any performance benefit. Martin has tidied the code up a bit, but the basic regex costs seem to be much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions such as `\p{IsIPAExtensions}` should be reasonably efficient: most of the blocks are a single consecutive range of codepoints and testing a character should simply check whether it is in that range. The cost, I suspect, arises not so much from the cost of checking one character against one Unicode block, but from the number of characters and the number of blocks.

It might be worth getting a profile at the Java level to see where it is spending its time. I can guess, but a profile would reveal if my guess is right.

The thing that can kill performance with regular expressions is backtracking, but I don't immediately see any risk of backtracking with this code.

The only other approach that comes to mind is to generate an enormous `translate()` call that classifies characters into groups (so all latin characters become "1", all Cyrillic characters become "2", etc) and then to process the result using `<xsl:for-each-group select="string-to-codepoints(.)" group-adjacent=".">. But there's no guarantee that would perform any better, and it's a lot of work to do the experiments to find out.

Comment: Thank you, Michael! With my code: the Tree is built in 181.7456ms Tree size: 40488 nodes, 668645 characters, 5271 attributes Execution time: 51.580351s (51580.3516ms) Memory used: 15 988 264. With Martin Honnen's code : Tree built in 132.5814ms
Tree size: 40488 nodes, 668645 characters, 5271 attributes
Execution time: 2.97471s (2974.7104ms)
Memory used: 15 179 008

Comment: Mine: 

Tree built in 327.6848ms Tree size: 240934 nodes, 11022801 characters, 26129 attributes Execution time: 10m 22.454917s (622454.9176ms) Memory used: 56 700 640

Martin Honnen's: 
Tree built in 319.7374ms
Tree size: 231455 nodes, 11003537 characters, 26129 attributes

Execution time: 18.269028s (18269.0285ms)
Memory used: 64 821 744

Comment: Do I understand correctly that backtracking is done in a more efficient way with xsl:iterate than with all the call-templates I used?

Comment: Neither xsl:iterate nor call-template bears any relation to regex backtracking, so I'm confused by the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I misused the word backtracking. I was guessing that the difference in time was not due to the use of regex, but rather due to the method used to iterate through text nodes. But I am really just a beginner with no IT background and I actually cannot see what I should do to calculate the time spent on regex only...